# LinearLayout doesn't show view

Tags: android, xml-layout

I'm using a `LinearLayout` that doesn't show every view.

This is the xml-code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="de.schumann_connection.yahtzee.DescriptionColumnFragment">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="de.schumann_connection.yahtzee.DescriptionColumnFragment">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#FF000000" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:text=""/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#FF000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

There are much more controls contained but this is enough to demonstrate the problem.

This should draw a black rectangle. But the right vertical line is missing.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add weight to the inner LinearLayout `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF000000" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:text="Hola"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000" />
```

Comment: you're using all width with android:layout_width="match_parent" using weight you avoid the problem ;)

Comment: if you find the answer appropriate, please mark as solved ;)

Comment: Currently I didn't understand the meaning of weight but I'll look for some more information. Nevertheless I'm still of the opinion that my way is not the way to go to do what I want. I'll try a TableView - hopefully it's what I need.

Comment: Of course this is not the best way, using custom drawable xml or a nine patch png is better and is the suggested

Answer (score 1):

THis is the wrong way to do what you're trying to do.  You want a text view with a black background around it?  Just add padding to your TextView on all sides and set the background color.

Comment: No that's not what I'm trying to do. There are some more controls in it. I tried to create some fragments and I tried them to add to a table - but I wasn't able to create a table and add some columns at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried a TableView?  You may have oversimplified your example here.

Comment: I'll try a TableView - thx. I added the sentence _There are much more controls contained but this is enough to demonstrate the problem._ to make clear that there are more controls contained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "view" is even an object.

It looks like you would rather have a relative view, or maybe a textView or imageView.

In any case, the reason it's not showing up is because that thing doesn't exist.

Comment: View is an object.  However using one as a spacer usually means that the author is doing something wrong, its a very inefficient way of doing things.  It was more frequently used 3 or 4 years ago when people were coming up to speed on the platform.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong. The problem is that I'm a C# developer but that's the first android program that I'm trying to create.

Comment: @Verarind Sorry, that wasn't meant as a dig.  A lot of old answers will show using a view like that.  Its one of those things that works, but was found to be a bad practice over time.  You'll still sometimes see it in fast and dirty code though.

Answer (score 0):

You have set view background color as transparency "android:background="#FF000000"" replace the color code "android:background="#FF0000""

Comment: And why does all the other lines appear as expected?

Comment: I am not sure, i guess , in design has view, width is 1dp with transparency, in that space(1dp) its parents background color will visible